# How to count columns with values

Tags: r

In my data I have 6 columns with values. Some of the participants have NA's and others have some values in there. Now I want to count +1 for each participant if they have a value in there and 0 if they have nothing, so an NA, in there. It doesnt matter which values are in the columns, just if there are values.
How would I do that? Would that be possible with an ifelse function?

for example

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 -> 1
NA NA NA NA NA NA -> 0
1 3 5 7 9 11 -> 1
```

Comment: Is it possible for a participant to have both NA values and actual values? Is it then to be considered 0 or 1?

Comment: Hi nero7! Welcome on StackOverflow! In order to help you, you need to provide an example of your initial data and an example of the expected result. The one you provided so far is not really clear: those are not even R objects. Try to share the code you created so far as well. Also: are columns and participants the same thing for you?

Comment: NA's and actual values are thought for different participants. it was thought like the example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(data=rep.int(c(1, 2, NA), 12), ncol=6))

df$test_not_na <- apply(df, 1, FUN=function(x){as.integer(!any(is.na(x)))})

df

#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 test_not_na
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1       1
# 2  2  2  2  2  2  2       1
# 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA       0
# 4  1  1  1  1  1  1       1
# 5  2  2  2  2  2  2       1
# 6 NA NA NA NA NA NA       0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Thx for the example and help

Comment: But how do I switch the 0 and 1 in this example?

Comment: You use an exclamation mark to invert the result of the "any" logical test:

df$test_na <- apply(df, 1, FUN=function(x){as.integer(!any(is.na(x)))})

I've updated the answer to include this

Comment: That's just great! Thank you :)

Comment: No problem - please accept the answer if it satisfies your question